Create LineStrings from Points with max number of points per LineString, no crossing, unique points per LineString
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import itertools
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, MultiLineString

points = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                     'Y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=points.X, y=points.Y))
gdf_points = gdf_points['geometry']

max_string = 3
start_point = Point(2, 0.5)


Target:

create LineStrings starting at the red point, start_point
a string should in maximum connect max_string Points
start a new string at start_point if the LineString connects max_string Points
the lines should not cross
a point should not connect multiple lines

One of 80 solutions could be:

My approach:
def points_on_multiple_lines(points, lines):
    for point in points:
        is_on_line = 0
        for line in lines:
            if line.dwithin(point, 0.0):
                is_on_line += 1

                start = Point(line.coords[0])
                end = Point(line.coords[1])
                if (not point.equals(start)) and (not point.equals(end)):
                    return False

        if is_on_line >= 3:
            return False
    return True

def lines_not_touch(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for i in lines:
            if line.crosses(i):
                return False

    return True


valid_lines = []
for shuffled_points in itertools.permutations(gdf_points):
    string_line = []
    complete_line = []
    for i, point in enumerate(shuffled_points):
        if i == 0:
            start_line = LineString([start_point, point])
            complete_line.append(start_line)
        elif i % max_string == 0:
            start_line = LineString([start_point, point])
            complete_line.append(start_line)
        else:
            current_line = LineString([shuffled_points[i - 1], point])
            complete_line.append(current_line)

    if points_on_multiple_lines(shuffled_points, complete_line) and lines_not_touch(complete_line):
        valid_lines.append(MultiLineString(complete_line))

With many Points the execution time will rapidly increase. You have any idea how to improve the code or if there is some package out there that helps?

I also get 80 valid_lines and the solution shown is the very first one in that list. You plotted the entire list, i assume

I really dug into it and was able to get it to compute all valid lines in approximately 5s instead of 25s with your code.
[EDIT]
Here is a little benchmark with various parameters. You can see a boost of 75% to 98% in run time depending on the case.



run
nb points
max_string
nb combinations
run time (new)
run time (original)
difference




0
8
2
34
4.3
27.55
-84%


1
8
3
81
5.49
25.41
-78%


2
8
4
108
6.23
24.48
-75%


3
8
5
120
6.33
23.85
-73%


4
10
2
89
44.18
2607.98
-98%


5
10
3
274
223.26
2367.66
-91%


6
10
4
401
320.23
2243.11
-86%


7
10
5
464
333.96
2074.29
-84%




Also, it scales well with a large number of points since not all combinations are created and tested for requirements. I ran the tests on a machine with a 16-cores i7-13700F and 64GB RAM.
The main difference between my approach and yours is the amount of power required :

RAM peaked up to ~19GB used by the heaviest case (compared to ~600MB)
CPU run at 100% most of the time during computation

[END EDIT]
Here is my approach :
1. Find the list of working combinations in terms of number of points per line
In your case you want to use all 8 points with lines ranging from 1 point to 3 points so all combinations of line lengths are :

(2, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 3, 3)
(1, 2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

2. Create all possible lines starting from start_point
3. Create all combinations of lines based on the length combinations
4. Select only combinations where there are no duplicate points between the lines
5. Select combinations where lines do not intersect or touch except at start_point
and voila :
import os
import itertools
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

def find_combinations(numbers, target):
    valid_combinations = []
    for r in range(1, target + 1):
        # The use of itertools.combinations_with_replacement allows for duplicates in combinations.
        # For example, summing to 4 with 1 and 2 can be (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2).
        combinations_list = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(numbers, r)
        for comb in combinations_list:
            if sum(comb) == target:
                valid_combinations.append(comb)
    return valid_combinations


def find_all_lines(points, max_length, start_point):
    # We create a dictionary to group available lines by length.
    lines = {length: [] for length in range(1, max_length + 1)}
    for r in range(1, max_length + 1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(points, r):
            line = [start_point] + list(combination)
            lines[r].append(LineString(line))
    return lines

def filter_combinations_chunk(target_comb_chunk, lines):
    all_combinations = []
    
    for comb in target_comb_chunk:
        combs = []
        count = Counter(comb)
        
        # Get the combinations for each length of line.
        for element, cnt in count.items():
            combs.append(itertools.combinations(lines[element], cnt))
        
        # Use itertools.product to find all combinations when multiple lengths are mixed
        combinations_list = list(itertools.product(*combs))
        
        # Flatten the combinations (no tuples)
        for comb in combinations_list:
            flat_comb = []
            for sub_comb in comb:
                flat_comb.extend(sub_comb)
            all_combinations.append(flat_comb)
               
    return all_combinations

def filter_combinations(lines, target_combs, parallel=True):
    
    all_combinations = []
    
    if parallel:
        # Split the target_combs into chunks
        num_workers=min(os.cpu_count(), len(target_combs))
        n = len(target_combs) // num_workers
        chunk_size = n if n>0 else 1
        chunks = [target_combs[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(target_combs), chunk_size)]
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(filter_combinations_chunk, chunk, lines) for chunk in chunks]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                all_combinations.extend(future.result())
    else:
    
        for comb in target_combs:
            
            combs = []
            count = Counter(comb)
            
            # We get the combinations for each length of line.
            # For example if a combination of length is (1, 2, 2, 3),
            # it will return all :
            #   - 1-element long lines
            #   - pairs of 2-elements long lines
            #   - 3-element long lines
            for element, cnt in count.items():
                combs.append(itertools.combinations(lines[element], cnt))
            
            # Use itertools.product to find all combinations when multiple lengths are mixed
            combinations_list = list(itertools.product(*combs))
            
            # Flatten the combinations (no tuples)
            for comb in combinations_list:
                flat_comb = []
                for sub_comb in comb:
                    flat_comb.extend(sub_comb)
                all_combinations.append(flat_comb)  
    
    return all_combinations


def remove_duplicate_points_chunk(chunk):
    # This is a worker for parallel mode
    unique_combinations = []
    for comb in chunk:
        points_used = set()
        valid = True
        for line in comb:
            points_in_line = list(line.coords)[1:]
            for point in points_in_line:
                if point in points_used:
                    valid = False
                    break
                points_used.add(point)
            if not valid:
                break
        if valid:
            unique_combinations.append(comb)
    return unique_combinations

def remove_duplicate_points(combinations, parallel=True):
    unique_combinations = []
    
    if parallel:
        num_workers=os.cpu_count()
        # chunk_size = len(combinations) // num_workers
        chunk_size = 40000
        chunks = [combinations[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(combinations), chunk_size)]
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(remove_duplicate_points_chunk, chunk) for chunk in chunks]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                unique_combinations.extend(future.result())  
    else:
        for comb in combinations:
            points_used = set()
            valid = True
            for line in comb:
                points_in_line = list(line.coords)[1:]
                for point in points_in_line:
                    if point in points_used:
                        valid = False
                        break
                    points_used.add(point)
                if not valid:
                    break
            if valid:
                unique_combinations.append(comb)
    
    return unique_combinations


def remove_intersecting_lines_chunk(chunk, start_pnt):
    non_intersecting_combinations = []

    for comb in chunk:
        valid = True
        for i in range(len(comb)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(comb)):
                line1 = comb[i]
                line2 = comb[j]
                
                # Exclude intersections at the start point
                if line1.intersects(line2):
                    intersection = line1.intersection(line2)
                    if not (isinstance(intersection, Point) and intersection.equals(start_pnt)):
                        valid = False
                        break
            if not valid:
                break
        if valid:
            non_intersecting_combinations.append(comb)

    return non_intersecting_combinations

def remove_intersecting_lines(combinations, start_pnt, parallel=True):
    non_intersecting_combinations = []
    
    if parallel:
        # Split the combinations into chunks
        num_workers=os.cpu_count()
        chunk_size = len(combinations) // num_workers
        chunks = [combinations[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(combinations), chunk_size)]
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(remove_intersecting_lines_chunk, chunk, start_pnt) for chunk in chunks]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                non_intersecting_combinations.extend(future.result())
    else:
        for comb in combinations:
            valid = True
            for i in range(len(comb)):
                for j in range(i + 1, len(comb)):
                    line1 = comb[i]
                    line2 = comb[j]
                    
                    # Exclude intersections at the start point
                    if line1.intersects(line2):
                        intersection = line1.intersection(line2)
                        if not (isinstance(intersection, Point) and intersection.equals(start_pnt)):
                            valid = False
                            break
                if not valid:
                    break
            if valid:
                non_intersecting_combinations.append(comb)
    
    return non_intersecting_combinations

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    debug = True
    parallel = True
    
    # Data setup
    points = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                        'Y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

    gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=points.X, y=points.Y))
    gdf_points = gdf_points['geometry']
    max_string = 3
    start_point = Point(2, 0.5)
    
    # Find length combinations for using all points
    total_points = len(points)
    target_combinations = find_combinations([i for i in range(1, max_string + 1)], total_points)
    if debug:
        print(f"{len(target_combinations)} combinations that sum to {total_points}:")
        for comb in target_combinations:
            print(comb)
    
    # Find all possible lines
    all_lines = find_all_lines(gdf_points, max_string, start_point)
    if debug:
        print(f"{np.sum([len(all_lines[group]) for group in all_lines])} lines available")
    
    # Create lines combinations based on length compatibility
    filtered_combinations = filter_combinations(all_lines, target_combinations, parallel=parallel)
    if debug:
        print(f"{len(filtered_combinations)} combinations that use all points")
        
    # Remove combinations with duplicate points
    unique_combinations = remove_duplicate_points(filtered_combinations, parallel=parallel)
    if debug:
        print(f"{len(unique_combinations)} combinations with no duplicates")
        
    # Remove combinations with intersecting lines
    non_intersecting_combinations = remove_intersecting_lines(unique_combinations, start_point, parallel=parallel)
    if debug:
        print(f"{len(non_intersecting_combinations)} non-intersecting combinations")

I used concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to parallelize execution, but it can disabled with a parallel=False flag. If the code is run in serial mode, the search for duplicate points takes 12s on my computer, instead of 6s in parallel.
If you want to plot, i made a piece of code for plotting single combinations or batches of subplots :
# OPTIONAL: Plotting the results
    plot = False
    plot_all = False
    subplot = True 
    
    if plot:
        
        if plot_all:
            i_max = len(non_intersecting_combinations)
        else:
            i_max = 5
            
        for i, comb in enumerate(non_intersecting_combinations):
            
            if i<i_max:        
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                
                cmap = mpl.colormaps['viridis'].resampled(len(comb))
                
                # Plot each valid line with a different color
                for j, line in enumerate(comb):
                    x, y = line.xy
                    ax.plot(x, y, color=cmap.colors[j], linewidth=2)
                    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=cmap.colors[j])

                # Plot the start point in red
                ax.plot(start_point.x, start_point.y, 'ro')

                # Set labels and title
                ax.set_xlabel('X')
                ax.set_ylabel('Y')
                ax.set_title('Non-Crossing LineStrings from Start Point')

    if subplot:
        
        # Number of subplots per figure
        max_subplots_per_fig = 40
        ncols = 10
        nrows = 4

        # Calculate the number of figures needed
        num_figs = (len(non_intersecting_combinations) + max_subplots_per_fig - 1) // max_subplots_per_fig

        for fig_idx in range(num_figs):
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20, 8))
            fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)
            axs = axs.ravel()
            
            for i in range(max_subplots_per_fig):
                comb_idx = fig_idx * max_subplots_per_fig + i
                if comb_idx >= len(non_intersecting_combinations):
                    break
                
                comb = non_intersecting_combinations[comb_idx]
                ax = axs[i]
                
                cmap = mpl.colormaps['viridis'].resampled(len(comb))
                
                for j, line in enumerate(comb):
                    x, y = line.xy
                    ax.plot(x, y, color=cmap.colors[j], linewidth=2)
                    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=cmap.colors[j])
                
                ax.plot(start_point.x, start_point.y, 'ro')
                ax.set_title(f'Combination {comb_idx + 1}', fontsize=8)
                
                ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
            
            # Hide unused subplots
            for k in range(i+1, len(axs)):
                fig.delaxes(axs[k])
                
            fig.tight_layout()
            
    plt.show()




Hope it helps !
I don't know if it could be improved again, but it a step forward in optimizing your approach.
